# Having a hard time with has_and_belongs_to_many associations. Not sure how to add objects to a specified instance of its "belongs_to" table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, associations, model-associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm building an app where a User can create a Group and then invite other Users to join his group. A User can join many Groups and a Group will include many Users. **I'm confused as to how I can add a specified user to a specified group.** For example I have a User object who's id is 2. **How do I take this User object and add it to a specified group?** I'm able to create a group with User.first.groups.create but I'm unable to do the reverse.

For example I tried: Group.first.create(user_id: 1) to add User 1 to Group 1. Rails didn't like that.

I have the following database design:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :share_link
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I also created a join table with the following migration:

```
class GroupsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :group_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :groups_users
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user = User.find(2) # this is user object you say you have already
group.users << user
group.save
```

`group` is the specific group you are adding to (in your quick example, it'd be `Group.first`.